# How to sort large numbers stored in a string array?

Tags: c#, sorting

I need to sort the large numbers stored as string in string array but my algorithm and .net built Array sort method doesn't work.

I tried to convert the number into `long` or `ulong` but that throw exception of overflow.

Here is the code that I tried:

```
string[] unsorted = { "1","2","100","12303479849857341718340192371",
                      "3084193741082937","3084193741082938","111","200" };

for (int index = 0; index < unsorted.Length - 1; index++)
{
    for (int count = 0; count < unsorted.Length - index - 1; count++)
    {
        if (string.Compare(unsorted[count], unsorted[count + 1]) == 1)
        {
            string temp = unsorted[count];
            unsorted[count] = unsorted[count + 1];
            unsorted[count + 1] = temp;
        }
    }
}
```

Also used the following method:

```
 Array.Sort(unsorted);
```

The array should be sorted correctly.

Comment: The count for loop you only need to compare numbers that are the same length.  So I would do following : var groups = unsorted.OrderBy(x => x.length).GroupBy(x => x.Length),ToArray();

Answer (score 4):

You could use [`BigInteger.Parse`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.numerics.biginteger?view=netframework-4.8) and use Linq's `OrderBy` on it. For example:

```
var sorted = unsorted.Select(BigInteger.Parse).OrderBy(e => e).ToArray();
```

If you need it back as string:

```
var sorted = unsorted.Select(BigInteger.Parse).OrderBy(e => e).Select(e => e.ToString()).ToArray();
```

This has a drawback in converting it first to a `BigInteger`, but probably you need it anyway. However compared to IO and Database access, this nothing adds to a typical application performance.

- Pro: Readable
- Contra: Probably not the most efficient solution.

Comment: Big Integer isn't supported in .Net 4.6

Comment: [Sure it is](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.numerics.biginteger?view=netframework-4.8#applies-to) @EngrUmair

Answer (score 3):

Try following :

```
string[] unsorted = { "1","2","100","12303479849857341718340192371",
                      "3084193741082937","3084193741082938","111","200" };

var groups = unsorted.OrderBy(x => x.Length).GroupBy(x => x.Length).ToArray();
List<string> results = new List<string>();
foreach (var group in groups)
{
    string[] numbers = group.ToArray();
    for(int i = 0; i < numbers.Count() - 1; i++)
    {
        for(int j = i + 1; j < numbers.Count(); j++)
        {
            if(numbers[i].CompareTo(numbers[j]) == 1)
            {
                string temp = numbers[i];
                numbers[i] = numbers[j];
                numbers[j] = temp;
            }
        }
    }
    results.AddRange(numbers);
}
```

Comment: I fixed issue.  I saw mistake after posting.

Comment: This will not be robust if some strings have prepended zeroes. This is not necessarily a requirement though.

Comment: this has n^3 complexity, by the I need to use bubble sort

Comment: It is not n^3.  It is less than  2*(n^2).  You first need to order by the length of the strings.  The only numbers you need to bubble sort are the ones of the same length.

Comment: Complexity here is N^3.

Comment: To be fair it does depend on the distribution of the input data. If there length of string is bounded then complexity is N^3.

Comment: I f you do two bubble sorts than it is 2*(n^2), not n^3.

Comment: You don't do two bubble sorts. And even if you did that would be O(N^2). As would three bubble sorts, four bubble sorts etc.

Comment: Yes you do.  First you sort by length (n^2)/2, then enumerate the groups n, then bubble sort each length (n^2)/2.  Results : (n^2) + n.

Comment: Well no, `OrderBy` isn't bubble sort. And for complexity analysis you ignore constant multipliers. What matters is the growth with N, not how long each iteration takes.

Comment: When comparing complexity there are cases when you do consider constant multiplier like when you are trying to decide which algorithm to use.  The worse case complexity is in the order of n^2 and no where near n^3.  With the grouping the worse case is when you have one group (all strings the same length).  As you have more groups the complexity decreases to n (all string different length where no sort is required).

Answer (score 2):

You don't have an array of numbers, you have an array of strings.  So they're being sorted alpha-numerically.

One option would be to use [the `BigInteger` class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.numerics.biginteger) to store them as numbers:

```
BigInteger[] unsorted = { 
    BigInteger.Parse("1"),
    BigInteger.Parse("2"), 
    BigInteger.Parse("100"),
    BigInteger.Parse("12303479849857341718340192371"),
    BigInteger.Parse("3084193741082937"),
    BigInteger.Parse("3084193741082938"),
    BigInteger.Parse("111"),
    BigInteger.Parse("200")
};
```

Failing that, if you want to keep them as strings then you can left-pad them with zeros to make the lengths consistent so the alphanumeric sorting would work:

```
string[] unsorted = { 
    "00000000000000000000000000001",
    "00000000000000000000000000002",
    "00000000000000000000000000100",
    "12303479849857341718340192371",
    "00000000000003084193741082937",
    "00000000000003084193741082938",
    "00000000000000000000000000111",
    "00000000000000000000000000200"
};
```

If you choose the former, just change the types in your `if` block to also be `BigInteger` as well.

Comment: The op wants to sort using strings not Big Int.  The string sort is simple using my solution and will run quicker than converting to a big int.

Answer (score 2):

If we want to sort very big numbers stored as strings, without changing string to `BigInteger`, it's better sort them according to it's length at first and then according to lexicographic order. We can see the sample code below:

```
using System;
using System.Linq;
public class Test
{
   public static void Main()
   {
     string[] unsorted = { "1","2", "100","12303479849857341718340192371",
                       "3084193741082937","3084193741082938","111","200" };

      unsorted.OrderBy(s => s.Length).ThenBy(s => s);
      Console.WriteLine("Sorted numbers are:");
      foreach (var x in unsorted) {
           Console.WriteLine(x);
      }
   }
}
```

Note: In order to use `OrderBy` and `ThenBy` functionality , we have to include `using System.Linq` to our program.

Answer (score 0):

For an elegant solution you can use **linq**, you will have a minimum of code with good performance.

```
var result = unsorted.Select(e => decimal.Parse(e)).OrderBy(e => e);
```

Comment: If you're going to use `decimal`, then you probably should warn the OP about its limitation (i.e., 16 bytes max.). Although this will work for the examples in the questions, add another digit to the fourth number and `decimal.Parse()` will fail.

Comment: @ahmed I agree with you, but the question was on how to order a table containing numbers according to a string format personally I would put in question the reason for using string in place of integer .

Answer (score 0):

The system must be like following. You can transfer values in the array to an arraylist then you can parse them all to **BigInteger** by for loop. And finally you can sort the list :

```
BigInteger[] unsorted; 
var bigIntegers = new List<System.Numerics.BigInteger>();

  for (int index = 0; index < unsorted.Length - 1; index++)
  {
  bigIntegers[i] = BigInteger.Parse[i]
  }

bigIntegers.sort();
```

Answer (score 0):

Another variation:

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        List<string> unsorted = new List<string>(new string[] {"1","2","100","12303479849857341718340192371",
                        "3084193741082938","3084193741082937", "111","200" });

        unsorted.Sort((x, y) => (x.Length != y.Length ? x.Length.CompareTo(y.Length) : x.CompareTo(y)));

        foreach(string number in unsorted)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(number);
        }
        Console.Write("Press Enter to quit");
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Building upon [@jdweng's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56309572/2819245), but further reducing it by eliminating the 'manual' bubble sort:

```
string[] result =
    unsorted.OrderBy(x => x.Length)
    .GroupBy(x => x.Length)
    .SelectMany(x => x.OrderBy(y => y))
    .ToArray();
```

Or some other variation of the same theme:

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;

...

string[] result =
    unsorted.OrderBy(x => x, Comparer<string>.Create((a, b) => a.Length == b.Length ? a.CompareTo(b) : a.Length - b.Length))
    .GroupBy(x => x.Length)
    .SelectMany(x => x)
    .ToArray();
```

(As noted by @fester's comment underneath @jdweng's answer, this approach will not work reliably if some of the strings are numbers with prepended zeros, such as "*00123*" for example.)

Answer (score 0):

```
    package com.solution.sorting;

    import java.util.Arrays;
    import java.util.Comparator;

    public class ArraySort {

        public static void main(String[] args) {
            String[] number = { "3", "2", "4", "10", "11", "6", "5", "8", "9", "7" };
            String[] unsorted = { "8", "1", "2", "100", "12303479849857341718340192371", "3084193741082937",
                    "3084193741082938", "111", "200" };

            Arrays.sort(number);
            for (String s : number)
                System.out.println("number="+s);
                //

                Arrays.sort(unsorted, new Comparator<String>() {

                    @Override
                    public int compare(String o1, String o2) {
                        
                        return compareStrings(o1,o2);//Integer.valueOf(o1).compareTo(Integer.valueOf(o2));
                    }

                });
            for (String s : unsorted)
                System.out.println("number1=" + s);

        }

        private static int compareStrings(String s1, String s2) {
            
            //
            if (s1.length() < s2.length()) {
                return -1;
            } else if (s1.length() > s2.length()) {
                return 1;
            }
            for (int i = 0; i < s1.length(); i++) {
                if ((int) s1.charAt(i) < (int) s2.charAt(i))
                    return -1;
                if ((int) s1.charAt(i) > (int) s2.charAt(i))
                    return 1;

            }
            return 0;

        }

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

For extremely large numbers where Primitive Data Types might fail, create a Comparator that first sorts the String by length and then sorts the String by the value of the same length.

```java
        Arrays.sort(array, new Comparator<String>() {
            @Override
            public int compare(String o1, String o2) {

                /** Sort by Length */

                if (o1.length() < o2.length()) {
                    return -1;
                }
                if (o1.length() > o2.length()) {
                    return 1;
                }

                /** Sort by the value of the same Length */

                return o1.compareTo(o2);
            }
        });
```

Comment: This idea seems to have already been proposed in [an earlier answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56309581/10871073).